# patch without reject

Tags: diff, patch

This might be answered already but it is hard to search for -- basically,

When `patch` find a block/hunk unable to apply, it will reject the changed hunk into reject file.

How not to put the conflicts in reject file but include in the final output, ***just*** as when `git` find the conflicts and [include both versions in the final output](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts):

```
$ cat merge.txt
<<<<<<< HEAD
this is some content to mess with
content to append
=======
totally different content to merge later
>>>>>>> new_branch_to_merge_later
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU patch has [a `--merge` option](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html):

```
--merge or --merge=merge or --merge=diff3
  Merge a patch file into the original files similar to diff3(1)
  or merge(1).  If a conflict is found, patch outputs a warning
  and brackets the conflict with <<<<<<< and >>>>>>> lines.  A
  typical conflict will look like this:

      <<<<<<<
      lines from the original file
      |||||||
      original lines from the patch
      =======
      new lines from the patch
      >>>>>>>

  The optional argument of --merge determines the output format
  for conflicts: the diff3 format shows the ||||||| section with
  the original lines from the patch; in the merge format, this
  section is missing.  The merge format is the default.

  This option implies --forward and does not take the --fuzz=num
  option into account.
```

Strangely I can't find this in [the GNU diffutils documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html) (where [other `patch` options](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#patch-Options) are documented).